# Configure phpstan with symfony

Tags: php, symfony, phpstan

I am getting a lot of errors related to phpunit like

> Class MyTest extends unknown class PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase

or

> Call to an undefined method MyTest::assertFalse().

I am on Symfony 6 and use the docker image of phpstan

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ghcr.io/phpstan/phpstan:1-php8.1
RUN composer global require phpstan/phpstan-phpunit phpstan/phpstan-doctrine phpstan/phpstan-symfony
```

My config:

```
parameters:
    symfony:
        containerXmlPath: /app/var/cache/dev/App_KernelDevDebugContainer.xml
    scanDirectories:
        - /app/vendor/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-9.5-0/vendor/
    scanFiles:
        - /app/vendor/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-9.5-0/vendor/autoload.php
includes:
    - /composer/vendor/phpstan/phpstan-symfony/extension.neon
    - /composer/vendor/phpstan/phpstan-symfony/rules.neon
    - /composer/vendor/phpstan/phpstan-phpunit/extension.neon
    - /composer/vendor/phpstan/phpstan-phpunit/rules.neon
```

What did I miss?

Comment: It could help to not run PHPStan on your test folder

Comment: I mean yeah. That would work. But I would also like to check my tests for bugs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of `scanFiles`:

```
    bootstrapFiles:
        - /app/vendor/bin/.phpunit/phpunit-9.5-0/vendor/autoload.php
```

Comment: So simple... I really thought I tried that... thanks